# Android GridView Adapter uses wrong position

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gridview

I'm developing with Xamarain Android on C# targeted at KitKat (4.4 - API19).

**Setting**

So I have this list of vehicles I wanted to render using the GridView. As this is within some tabbing the GridView is contained within a fragment to be created when first clicking on the corresponding tab (code not shown here). That works fine, the problem arises when the GarageFragmentAdapter starts to getting Views.
I made sure the fragment and adapter are only created once, so it is not an issue of multiple instances colliding with their works. I haven't attached any bells or whistles (scrolling reaction or item reaction) at the moment its just about the rendering.

**Problem**

In my example, I have 4 vehicles, so my list is 4 items long. The first call to the adapter uses position 0 (ok), the second call also uses position 0 (NOT ok) and then there is only a third call which uses position 1 (definitely not ok) and no fourth call. The visual output is then only two items being shown which is also not what I'd expect but I reckon the GridView uses the position to render an item AT position x.

So my question would be, how to I convince the adapter to correctly iterate through my data list?

**Code**

The code as seen below is the latest iteration, beforehand the adapter was set within the fragment, which I thought was the problem due to reading somewhere this can be an issue.

```
public class GarageFragment : Fragment
{
    private readonly VehiclesResponse _garageResponse;
    private readonly GarageFragmentAdapter _adapter;

    public GarageFragment(VehiclesResponse garageResponse, GarageFragmentAdapter adapter)
    {
        _garageResponse = garageResponse;
        _adapter = adapter;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var fragmentView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_garage, container, false);
        fragmentView.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridVehicleCards).Adapter = _adapter;
        fragmentView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowFullGarage).Visibility = _garageResponse.TotalCarsInGarageCount > 4 ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
        fragmentView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.boxAddVehicles).Visibility = _garageResponse.CanAddVehicles ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;

        return fragmentView;
    }
}

public class GarageFragmentAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Activity _context;
    private readonly IList<Vehicle> _tileList;

    public GarageFragmentAdapter(Activity context, IList<Vehicle> vehicles)
    {
        _context = context;
        _tileList = vehicles;
    }

    public override int Count => _tileList.Count;

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            var item = _tileList[position];
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BasicVehicleCard, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.vehicleName).Text = item.Name;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: add `Log.d` with `position` parameter inside `GetView`, what do you see?

Comment: @pskink D/Position( 1492): 0, D/Position( 1492): 0, D/Position( 1492): 1

Comment: is it called before `var view = convertView;` ?

Comment: yes, it was. I put it at the head of the member.

Comment: ok so now call `view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.vehicleName).Text = something` not only `if (view == null)` but always

Comment: no crashes, no changes

Comment: doesn't `ArrayAdapter` work? what is the reason for using a custom one?

Comment: I just followed the example provided on the xamarin documentation. But it turns out the problem comes from somewhere else. The space the GridView receives on the display defines how many items are rendered, not like I assumed the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears **GridView** does not work as I would expect. **It does not grow along with the provided content, it defines how much content it will show / load depending on the space it has.** (something which would have been nice to be stated in the documentation of the GridView)

As this is not feasible for my requirement I will instead use GridLayout and add the content element views therein.